# SQL: Multiple Foreign Keys for Inheritance

Tags: sql, inheritance, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a few tables in a database and I have a quick question regarding foreign keys.

## Tables

**Company**

```
PK: CompanyID
```

**Manufacturer**

```
PK, FK: CompanyID
```

**Make/Model**

```
PK: MakeModelID
FK: ManufacturerID
```

**Equipment**

```
PK: EquipmentID
FK: MakeModelID
```

Would it be proper to include a `ManufacturerID` column as a FK to Manufacturer in the `Equipment` table? And then would it be smart to create an Index on both `ManufacturerID` and `MakeModelID` in the `Equipment` table? I'm self taught and was just seeking some design input. Thanks.

Comment: And onteh index thing, no most databases do not automatically create an index on foreign keys, if you need one (and it is likely you do), you need to create it

Answer (score 2):

No, it would not be proper to include a FK to the manufacturer table in the equipment table.

The equipment table already has a FK to the Make/Model table which has the FK to the Manufacturer table. If you created that FK, then technically a record in the equipment table could be linked to two different manufacturers.

Comment: And if you were so foolish as to do such a thing, then you need a trigger on all the associated tables to make sure the ids stay in synch.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to include ManufacturerID in the Equipment table, since you already have MakeModelID, and the MakeModel table already has a ManufacturerID.  So you could join through the MakeModel table to get the ManufacturerID.